# How to execute a JS Script stored in a string on Html code stored in a string

Tags: javascript

I don't even know if what I'm asking is possible or not, I'm fairly new to web development.

Here is what I'd like to achieve:
I need to execute a JS script on a web page. The script returns some keywords related to that page.
I get the JS script from a remote server and I store it in a string.
The only thing I know about the web page is its url, so I get the content of the page with jQuery.

Here is what I tried (I know it looks stupid, but it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve):

```
// Let's say I want to execute that script on www.google.com's page
$.get("www.google.com", null, function(data) {

    let myScript = localStorage.getItem('my_script')

    // What I tried so far (it doesn't work, of course)
    var temp = document.createElement('div')
    temp.innerHTML = data
    var resultsOfMyScript = temp.firstChild.eval(myScript) // not a function
})
```

Do you have any idea on how I could do that?

Comment: Why not create a script element?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const script = document.createElement('script')

script.type = 'text/javascript'
script.charset = 'utf-8'
script.text = "console.log('this is my script')"

document.body.appendChild(script)
```

Substitute `.text` for the string you mentioned.

Comment: Do you mean `.textContent`?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. Setting `textContent` will insert the tag but won't execute the script. Setting the `text` property will :) try it in DevTools or see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Thanks slezica, but that would not take care of the remote page I'm trying to execute the script on (c.f. `data`in my code sample)

Comment: `.text` and `.textContent` appear to return same result http://plnkr.co/edit/WFbJpymutLKQqC2NvRRv?p=preview